Count values greater than row value in all previous rows in each group
I want to compare the numerical value of each row of groups with the previous rows of the same group and return the number of previous rows that have a value greater than the current row.
I know the general work and I know how to use the following formula for all the rows
a=df['column1'].to_numpy()

df['lesser_count']=np.triu(a<a[:,None].sum(0)

But I want it to work separately for each group in column2

this misses a dot .;  a=df['column1']to_numpy().  should be a=df['column1'].to_numpy()

Yes, unfortunately I forgot.
Can you guide me how to do this for each group separately?

The question is not clear, please provide an example dataframe and the expected result - minimal reproducible example.
